# How to implement a scenario outline in lettuce using pycharm

Tags: python, testing, bdd, pycharm, lettuce

I have the following feature:

```
Feature: Check if the weather service works properly
In order to check the weather service
As beginner
I'll get some values and check if they are ok and if the temperature given is correct

Scenario: Check if a city and and country given are correct
     Given I access the url with http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather
     And the city is <city> and the country <country>
     When I ask for the city and country name
     Then I check if the city and country are correct
     And I check if the status code is 200

  Examples:
    | city      | country |
    | London    | UK      |
    | Madrid    | ES      |
    | Barcelona | ES      |
    | Berlin    | GE      |
```

And I have the following step:

```
@step("the city is (.*) and the country (.*)")
def city_and_country(self, expectedCity, expectedCountry):
    world.expectedCity = expectedCity
    world.expectedCountry = expectedCountry
```

but when I execute this step I have the followin information:

[image]

I check the lettuce documentation and the scenario outline looks pretty well, but I still don´t understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my own question:

```
Scenario Outline: Check if a city and and country given are correct
Given I access the url with http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather
And the city is <city> and the country <country>
When I ask for the city and country name
Then I check if the city and country are correct
And I check if the status code is 200

Examples:
  | city      | country |
  | London    | GB      |
  | Madrid    | ES      |
  | Barcelona | ES      |
```

And the step definition is:

```
@step('the city is ([^"]+) and the country ([^"]+)')
def city_and_country(self, expectedCity, expectedCountry):
    world.expectedCity = expectedCity
    world.expectedCountry = expectedCountry
```

Hope it helps in a future!